# Power reduction formula $\cos^4x \sin^2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was able to use the power reduction formula and FOIL to reduce the $\cos^4x$ But I am stuck.  The length of the problem is complicating and I am not sure what can be combine.

$\cos^4x\sin^2x = \Big( \frac{3+ 4\cos(2x)+\cos(4x)}{8} \Big) \Big( \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2} \Big) $

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a practice in programming, not in Mathematics.

Comment: I think it would be easier to begin with $\cos^4x \sin^2x = \cos^4x - \cos^6x$

Comment: Thanks. I will see if it works.

Comment: How to you combine $ \Big( \frac{\cos(4x)}{8} \Big) \Big( \frac{-\cos(2x)}{2} \Big)$  I am stuck there.  I was wondering if a half angle identity would make the two terms more alike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides power reduction rules, there are also the polarized versions of sum/difference formulas:

$$ \cos(mx)\cos(nx)=\tfrac{1}{2}\cos((m-n)x)+\tfrac{1}{2}\cos((m+n)x) $$

$$ \sin(mx)\sin(nx)=\tfrac{1}{2}\cos((m-n)x)-\tfrac{1}{2}\cos((m+n)x) $$

$$ \sin(mx)\cos(nx)=\tfrac{1}{2}\sin((m-n)x)+\tfrac{1}{2}\sin((m+n)x) $$

(These follow from the usual sum/difference formulas and cancellation of signs.) This allows us to turn a product of any two of sine or cosine into a linear combination. Ultimately, with these we can turn any polynomial expression involving $\sin(kx)$s and $\cos(kx)$s into a linear combination of them, though there is no guarantee it will always be the most efficient.

Comment: This is great thanks for the direction.  I found some more stuff on product to sum that had the same formula in your answer.  I think I can get moving again and I hope to be on the home stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Hints (non-complex method):

1. Convert the $\sin^2 x$ term to $1-\cos^2 x$ and multiply; then factor out $\cos^2 x$.  You should get a square and a cube.
2. Use the identity $$\cos^2 x = \frac {1+\cos 2x} {2}$$ and $$\cos^3 x = \frac {\cos 3x + 3 \cos x}{4}$$
   There will be a lot of simplification to do, but the answer I got was $$\frac {1}{32}(2 + \cos 2x - 2 \cos 4x - \cos 6x)$$